# Removing Whitespace inside a <pre> Tag in an HTML E-Mail

Tags: html, css, email

I have an application that generates a HTML email using `velocity`.
One Expression generates output that I cannot control (it comes from a Jira Plugin):

```
<table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
    <tr>
    <td valign="top">
          <pre>#changesIncludingStatus([])</pre>
         </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The output contains Newlines, but no breaks. I'am trying to fix this using the pre.
But for some reason the lines are also idented with whitespace which looks weird in the HTML email.

```
<pre><div class="aptis-pre">            Bearbeiter: Vorgesetzter Mitarbeiter  (war: Administrator)
    Resturlaub: 23
    Beschreibung:
</div></pre>
```

results in 
[a strange display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R2GM8.png)

Is there any way to remove the whitespace at the start of every line?

Comment: The indentation is due to the <pre> tag

Comment: Just remove the space from above code.

Comment: I am looking for a way to get newlines to be displayed like breaks, but without the identation

Comment: I cant remove the space, i have no control over the output generated by the placeholder #changesIncludingStatus([])

Comment: Why dont ypu just do it with JavaScript or jquery?would you like me to provide the jquery code?

Comment: AFAIK you cant execute JS in an HTML email

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly what you want to do is to preserve line breaks but collapse spaces.

There is a CSS property to control this behavior: `white-space`. If set to `pre-line` it will exactly do this, from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/white-space):

> **pre-line**: sequences of whitespace are collapsed. Lines are broken at newline characters, at `<br>`, and as necessary to fill line boxes.

```css
.aptis-pre
{
  white-space: pre-line;
}
```

```html
<div class="aptis-pre">            Bearbeiter: Vorgesetzter Mitarbeiter  (war: Administrator)
    Resturlaub: 23
    Beschreibung:
</div>
```

Note that because you directly control `white-space` then you don't need to wrap that snippet into `<pre>` (which sets `white-space` to `pre` with preserved spaces).

Answer (score -1):

Just remove the `space`'s from your HTML. Format you code as below.

```html
<pre><div class="aptis-pre">            Bearbeiter: Vorgesetzter Mitarbeiter  (war: Administrator)
    Resturlaub: 23
    Beschreibung:
</div></pre>

<hr>

<pre><div class="aptis-pre">Bearbeiter: Vorgesetzter Mitarbeiter  (war: Administrator)
Resturlaub: 23
Beschreibung:
</div></pre>
```

Comment: i cant do that, i cant modify the output of the placeholder

Answer (score -1):

I found an alternative approach but couldn't quite get it to work:

```
#set ($changes = "#changesIncludingStatus([])")
#set ($changes = $changes.replace("\\n","<br/>"))
$changes
```

I cant get velocity to replace the breaks, but i'll go with the solution based on "white-space: pre-line;" by Adriano Repetti

Sorry its not worked out completely but maybe its gonna help somebody anyways.

Comment: Note that when string is copied into HTML it's also escaped and <br/> will become &lt;br/&gt; (with no effect). To make this work you should first manually escape, do substitution and then insert text as-is (without further escaping). Instead (I don't know _velocity_) if escaping isn't done (I doubt) then don't forget to do it or you may produce broken HTML e-mails.